# Thinking sphinx rails not running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Everytime I try to run Sphinx 2.0.1 with Rails 3 on Mac OSX Snow Leopard, I get the following error:

> ```
> Failed to start searchd daemon. Check /Users/.../log/searchd.log.
> Failed to start searchd daemon. Check /Users/.../log/searchd.log
> ```

And that's my backtrace

```
>
```

Sphinx 2.0.1-beta (r2792)

```
    Program compiled with gcc 4.2.1
    Host OS is Darwin ...s-macbook-pro.local 10.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.7.0: Sat Jan 29 15:17:16 PST 2011; root:xnu-1504.9.37~1/RELEASE_I386 i386
    Stack bottom = 0x7fff5fbfef1f, thread stack size = 0x12000
    begin of manual backtrace:
    Something wrong with thread stack, backtrace may be incorrect (fp=7fff5fbfc7a0)
    Stack looks OK, attempting backtrace.
    10000407f
    5fbfe14000000000
    7fff5fbfc960
    100054a5f
    100001dc8
    4
    Something wrong in frame pointers, backtrace failed (fp=0)
    begin of system backtrace:
    begin of system symbols:
    0   searchd                             0x000000010015d697 _Z12sphBacktraceib
+ 679
    1   searchd                             0x000000010000407f
_ZN16SphCrashLogger_c11HandleCrashEi + 415
    2   libSystem.B.dylib                   0x00007fff83ae666a _sigtramp + 26
    3   ???                                 0x00007fff5fbfc960 0x0 + 140734799792480
    4   searchd                             0x0000000100054a5f main + 95
    5   searchd                             0x0000000100001dc8 start + 52
    6   ???                                 0x0000000000000004 0x0 + 4
```

Did anyone run into this ? Does anyone know what's going on? And how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sphinx 2.0.1 doesn't work on OS X - you'll want to grab the source for 2.0.2-dev instead:

```
svn co http://sphinxsearch.googlecode.com/svn/trunk sphinx-read-only
```

Comment: This didn't work for me on OS X, running `make` on trunk gave me the error "pthread_mutex_timedlock was not declared in this scope".  A google search turns up [this thread](http://www.orocos.org/forum/rtt/rtt-dev/bug-684-new-trunk-fails-build-mac-pthreadmutextimedlock-not-available), where someone mentions it's fixed in revision 30387.  However, when I browse [trunk](http://sphinxsearch.googlecode.com/svn/trunk), the most recent revision is 2888.  Anyone have insight on resolving this error for 2.0.2-dev on OS X?

Comment: I ended up installing version 1.1.0 [from here](http://sphinxsearch.googlecode.com/svn/branches/rel110/) without problem on OS X in the meantime.

Comment: For anyone else encountering the same issue as me on OS X, it looks like there is a [bug report here](http://sphinxsearch.com/bugs/view.php?id=881).  Until it's fixed, you can checkout revision 2887 of the code and compile that without issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting same issue a month ago.

you can try

```
   ps -ef | grep searchd
```

Kill the running processes and then in from project directory.

```
   rake ts:index
   rake ts:start
```

*Ps:  I moved back to 0.9.9-release, but this solved issue on my  friend's machine but not mine.*